# What does 인 mean in 유명한 관광지인 와이키키?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence:

> 호놀룰루의 유명한 관광지**인** 와이키키 해변은 외국에서 여행을 오는 사람들로 복잡합니다.

I think 인 is used like 의 in this sentence. But I have never seen any such usage so far and in my dictionary there seems to be no such description for the word 인.

So what does this 인 work for grammatically?

Comment: Please refer to the third meaning of [-ㄴ](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&mainSearchWord=-%E3%84%B4&currentPage=1&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=78634&nation=eng&nationCode=6&viewType=A&blockCount=10&viewTypes=on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like these, -인 is not a 조사, like 의; it actually is a combination of -이다 and -ㄴ. -ㄴ combines with -이 from -이다 and makes -인.

ex)

내 아버지는 농구선수이다.
My father is a basketball player.

내 아버지는 키가 크다.
My father is tall.

농구선수**인** 내 아버지는 키가 크다.
My father, a basketball player, is tall.